# Wrong camera pose with respect to scale of objects in the scene

Tags: camera, transforms, scale

I am using the urban canyon Blender scene "Multi-FoV" Synthetic dataset from University of Zurich to create camera trajectories.
However, I see that the camera pose given by Blender doesn't match with the actual motion of the camera with respect to the scale and dimensions of the remaining objects in the scene.

[image: Camera location]

[image: Object location]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the question is here?  A link to the data-set, the results you are seeing (and how) vs expected result.

Comment: Here's the link to the dataset 
http://rpg.ifi.uzh.ch/fov.html